# MVC web portal with Azure Ad Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm having the errors described in the pictures below, no matter what I put in the reply urls I can't make it to authenticate successfully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that is quite weird. Is it a multi-tenant app?

Comment: @juunas it’s not I want to authenticate only with one AD. :/ I can’t figure it out.

Comment: Make sure the client id in the URL matches your client/application id also

Comment: As juunas commented that you need to make sure that the application Id in the above picture is the one you try to set the reply urls on Azure Portal. Or maybe you you just created the AD v2.0 app via `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/`, while the setting reply urls in the above picture is used for AD v1.0 app.